# How to ignore specific characters when reading a file?

Tags: c++

I have a file in specific format:

```
1000
0.00001 2.0004
1.00056 5.0006
11.0000006 3.088884
.
.
.
.
6.00004, 5.0006
1000
1.00001, 3.0000
.
.
.
.
3.00005, 1.0006
3000
.
.
.
4000
.
.
.
3000
```

As you can see the beginning of each set of points has a number, followed by the points in the file.

I want to be able to ignore the the 1000 and 2000 and 3000 and whatever there is that is not in format x y, and only store the points in my struct.

If there were no such points I know I could just open the file using ifstream and then do file >> my_struct.x_cord >> my_struct.y_cord but in this case I am not sure how to ignore all the lines with 1000, 2000, 3000, 6000 (aka lines which don't have two different points split by space).

So basically I just want the
0.0001 2.0004 lines and store them as x and y cord in my struct. I want to ignore the 1000 and 2000 and 3000 (which is basically number of points in that set).

Thanks!

Comment: Read the file one line at a time (e.g. using `std::getline()` to read a `std::string`).  Check the contents of the string.   If checking determines it doesn't contain two numeric values separated by a comma, discard it.   Read data from the strings that are not discarded.  Repeat until end of file reached.

Comment: Concerning _which is basically number of points in that set_ Why not `for (;;) { int n; in >> n; for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { in >> x >> y; } }`? (Appropriate error checking and bail out should be added, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way is to use regex:

```
struct Coordinates
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

void main()
{
    std::ifstream fileToRead("coordinates.txt");

    std::string line;

    std::vector<Coordinates> someCoordinates;

    while(getline(fileToRead, line))
    {
        std::regex rgx("(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\,?\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)");
        std::smatch matches;

        if (std::regex_search(line, matches, rgx))
        {
           Coordinates coord;
           coord.x = atof(matches[1].str().c_str());
           coord.y = atof(matches[2].str().c_str());
           someCoordinates.emplace_back(coord);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I go about converting that comma to space though. Since the points are in format 1.23 4.55. I tried " " instead of , but that doesn't match.

Comment: This regular expression match both a comma separator and a space separator. Do you want to match only the number separated by the space ?

Comment: So, it never does matches for me. I believe it's because my file has more than one space between the co-ordinates. I have put up a part of the data I imported into hastebin. https://hasteb.in/oqagiseg.http not sure how to fix it up though.

As for above comment, no, I still want to match both the points 1.4000    1.5555

Comment: To match more spaces between numbers you could add a quantifier after \s, replace \s with \s* : (\\d+\\.\\d+)\\,?\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets` to read input file line-by-line, then scan the the line by using `sscanf`.
Ref to sample code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fd;

   struct point_t
   {
      float x_cord;
      float y_cord;
   } point;

   char buffer[64];

   fd = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fd))
   {
      if ((2 == sscanf(buffer, "%f,%f", &point.x_cord, &point.y_cord))
         || (2 == sscanf(buffer, "%f%f", &point.x_cord, &point.y_cord)))
      {
         printf("== [X:%f, Y:%f]\n", point.x_cord, point.y_cord);
      }
   }

   fclose(fd);

   return 0;
}
```